# PyQt5 Display Function Output in Text Edit

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm attempting to create a GUI for an application that reads lines of text from a file onto a Plain Text Edit in PyQt5.  I'm very new to PyQt5 and created this GUI through the Designer in an attempt use PyQt5 to upgrade the GUI of an application I made using Tkinter.  I know the names of the "widgets" I need to utilize, but I don't know the proper way to write and format the code.  Below is an example of what I'm trying to do, but rather than display the text in the Text Edit, I am simply printing it out to the Python Shell.  It works fine.

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Display_Tweets)

def Display_Tweets(self):
    readtweets = open("Tweetfile", "r")
    tweetlist = readtweets.readlines()
    for x in tweetlist:
        print(x)
    readtweets.close()
```

This prints to Shell what I want displayed in the text edit box when I click the button, so all I should need to do is tell it to display "x" on the Text Edit, rather than print it.  Since I am new to PyQt5, I don't actually know the proper syntax for this, nor can I find any relevant up-to-date documentation.

So when I try and change the function to instead display the lines of the file on a Plain Text Edit widget I run into issues that I am pretty sure are because I am messing up the "grammar". The name of the Plan Text Edit widget is "plainTextEdit", but I'm not sure how to add text to it.  If I run the code below the GUI closes when I press the button.  Again the above code prints out to the Shell what I want displayed by the Text Edit, I just don't know how to get it into the Text Edit.  I've tried many variations on what I've shown here, but they all end with the GUI just closing on me.

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Display_Tweets)

def Display_Tweets(self):
    readtweets = open("Tweetfile", "r")
    tweetlist = readtweets.readlines()
    for x in tweetlist:
        self.plainTextEdit.append(x)
    readtweets.close()
```

What I'm trying can be accomplished in tkinter if you have a Text Edit box called "DisplayTweets" using the code below.  For tkinter you simply write the name of the text edit box, use the insert function, and then in the parantheses tell it where to add the line of text (in the code below I add it to the end of the text box) and then you tell it what to add.  So I've got this working in Tkinter, I just want to know how to do the same thing in PyQt5 and I haven't been able to find a good resource yet.

```
def Display_Tweets():
    readtweets = open("Tweetfile", "r")
    tweetlist = readtweets.readlines()
    for x in tweetlist:
        DisplayTweets.insert(END, x)        
    readtweets.close()
```

I want to add that I'm not sure why the user "eyllanesc" keeps referring this as a duplicate question of how to add multiple lines in a PlainTextEdit.  This is a question of how to add any line in a PlainText Edit as when I tried my GUI would close.  Never did I have a problem of adding only one line to a PlainTextEdit.  I get I'm new here, but I'm not going to let you try and walk over me because of it.  There are many new users struggling to learn the same things I am and you are not helping by referring users to a different question than the one I am asking.  Any new users please refer to the answers of the user "Lt Worf" instead of ellyanesc.  Lt Worf answered the question and gave incredibly good resources along with his answer.

Comment: You are asking 2 separate questions: "how to connect signal and slots in pyqt" and "how to change text", they should be asked in 2 separate questions, with minimal code example that actually can be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Lieutenant, but I seem to be getting the buttons to always function correctly.  The only issue I had was with the changing of text. I did read a little on signal and slots and I understand the concept, but in my new coding brain I just think you press stuff and that causes things to happen.  I try to keep it simple for now.  When I better understand signal and slots I'll probably have questions on them as well, but today is not that day.

Comment: Having marked your question as a duplicate does not invalidate the current answers of this post, it only indicates that there is already another question asking for the same thing you asked, the other question is to insert n lines and your question is a particular case for n = 1 . On the other hand that you are a beginner is irrelevant, with your logic would have to redo all the questions since there are always beginners and that is illogical for a site where we want to save resources and efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyQt is just a generated wrapper around Qt, so you need to use the Qt documentation for all the Qt objects you use.

For setting text, you can use `setText('blabla')`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setText

It supports both HTML for formatted text, or plain text.

To append text at the end, I do something like this

```
    txt.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
    txt.insertHtml(data + '<br>')
    txt.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
```

if I want to use HTML, otherwise `.append('blabla')` also works.

The moving cursor part is not necessary for append, but it's nice because it will make your text box scroll down as you keep adding stuff.

Comment: 1. Actually read the documentation I linked
2. "massive errors" means nothing, we consider errors for what they say, not for how many lines they print.
3. I copy pasted my code from a project that actually works, so I can assure you that it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for anyone else with a similar problem.  LtWorf answered my question, and the documentation he sent had the answer within it.  Obviously, I just answered the question for myself so I'm no expert, but I will answer in a way aimed at newbie idiots like myself.  In my bad code where I write

```
self.plainTextEdit.append(x)
```

I fail to tell the computer what type of text to expect.  Instead I need to write something like the code below, which tells it to append the output as plain text.

```
self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(x)
```

Or I can tell the computer to append the output as Html.

```
self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml(x)
```